# An oriented compact smooth manifold with boundary does not have a retraction onto its boundary

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

The following is Problem 16-4 of Lee's Introduction to Smooth manifolds.

> Suppose $M$ is an oriented compact smooth manifold with nonempty boundary. Show that there does not exist a retraction of $M$ onto its boundary. [Hint: if the retraction is smooth, consider an orientation form on $\partial M$.]

Suppose there is a smooth retraction $r:M\to\partial M$ and let $\iota: \partial M\hookrightarrow M$ be an inclusion so that $r\circ\iota = 1$. Let $\omega$ be an orientation form of $\partial M$. Then by Stoke's theorem,
\begin{align*}
\int_{\partial M} r^*\omega = \int_M d(r^*\omega) = \int_M r^*(d\omega) = 0.
\end{align*}
where the last equality follows from the fact that $d\omega = 0$. Since $r\circ\iota = 1$, we have
\begin{align*}
\int_{\partial M}r^*\omega = \int_{\partial M}\iota^*r^*\omega = \int_{\partial M}(r\circ\iota)^*\omega = \int_{\partial M}\omega.\end{align*}
Hence, we get
$$\int_{\partial M}\omega = 0.$$
which is a contradiction as $\omega$ is an orientation form of $\partial M$.

Now, suppose $\tilde{r}:M\to\partial M$ is just continuous. Then by Smooth approximation theorem, $\tilde{r}\simeq r$ where $r:M\to\partial M$ is smooth. Then $\tilde{r}\circ\iota = 1\simeq r\circ\iota$. Since $1$ and $r\circ\iota$ are smooth, we can choose a smooth homotopy $H:M\times I\to \partial M$ such that $H(x,0) = x$ and $H(x,1) = r\circ\iota(x)$. Now,
$$\int_{\partial (M\times I)}H^*\omega = \int_{M\times I}d(H^*\omega) = \int_{M\times I}H^*(d\omega) = 0.$$
I'm stuck in here. I need to express $\partial (M\times I)$ as a finite union of manifolds with boundary but can't see.

Comment: Do you already know that boundaries always have collar neighborhoods?  If so, then you can show that the existence of a continuous retraction implies the existence of a smooth one.

Comment: I think its possible to proceed without the use of collar neighbourhoods here (even though we can use collar neighbourhoods if following Lee chronologically, since its discussed in Chapter 9), given a continuous retraction $r : M \rightarrow \partial M$, $r$ is smooth on the closed subset $\partial M \subset M$ since $r \restriction \partial M = \text{id}_{\partial M}$, so the Whitney approximation theorem (Theorem 6.26 in Lee), gives that $r$ is homotopic relative to $\partial M$ to a smooth map $f$, then $f : M \rightarrow \partial M$ is a smooth retraction.